# Confuguring Apache to Act as a Proxy Server

Tags: mod-rewrite, proxy, virtual, host

Okie...was discussing this with a person doing a security review for a resturant chain.
The cafes have household wifi routers with common passwords and router setup un protected.

Is there a possibility of some one redirecting all web requests (80 & 81) to a web server that mod redirects requests for specific sites to locally hosted phishing pages (Assume the cracker enters the cafe, connected to the Wireless router and has a web server running on his notebook).

It may be noted than the web server is not directly connected to the internet. It connects using the same router. By making a change in the router config, can one redirect all web requests to the crackers local apache server that uses MOD rewrite  to forward users trying to visit specific sites to locally hosted phishing pages thereby not being tied to any traceable ip / Web Hoting Account

If yes. How can one direct traffic to the local apache server...using port fowrding or static routes ? [Clearly I suck at router config]

If port 80/81 requests are forwarded to a Local IPs, are external URIs  automatically routed to the WAN on a different port (if this is what " The WAN HTTP port of CPE will be changed to 8080 if submit successfully" means - got that notification when I forwarded all port 80 connections on the router to a Local IP).

All web requests must flow thru the cracker's machine that should acts as a Proxy. Can this be accomplished by changing the WIFI router config alone (say by creating a virtual host or by conmfiguring Static Routes) ?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want help with configuring your router? Or an detailed how-to for man-in-the-middle-attacks on wifi-users? Or anything in between? - Please refer to the [FAQ] for a quide on what kind of questions to ask or not to ask! Maybe you can give a specific problem you encountered and ask about help with that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can tell browsers like Firefox to direct traffic to a proxy server like Squid and intercept the traffic. However, you need to run some security software if you operate an internet cafe. The software will reset all defaults

Comment: Very clearly i cant disturb proxy settings in the users browser if thsts what u mean...can't the same be effected by changing router config.